# Llenar el contenido de un array entre clases

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android, y necesito que desde un activity se pueda llenar un array creado en otra clase ya que desde un segundo activity obtendré los datos creados, sin embargo no logro agregar datos al array desde el primer activity.

```
//CLASE QUE MANDA INSERTA EL ARRAY
public class ProductoDetailFragment extends Fragment {


Array array = new Array();

String K = "";

private static ProductoDetailFragment myself;

public ProductoDetailFragment() {
    myself = this;
}

public static ProductoDetailFragment getInstance() {
    return myself;
}

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

ArrayList<String> orray = new ArrayList<String>();

private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.Nombre);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre)).setText(mItem.Nombre + "\n");
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtClave)).setText(mItem.Clave + "\n");
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion)).setText(mItem.Descripcion + "\n");
        K = mItem.Nombre;
        Log.v(TAG, "eee" + K);

    }

    return rootView;
}

public void grr(){
    array.insertar(K);
    Log.v(TAG, array.getLista().toString());
}

public ArrayList<String> listarArray(){
    return array.getLista();
}

}
```

Cabe destacar que en el método OnCreate lleno la variable k para que no me de error, ya lo comprobe con un Log, si hay valor de retorno. A continuación la clase que contiene el array

```
//CLASE QUE CONTIENE EL ARRAY
public class Array {
private  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();


public void insertar(String valor){
    array.add(valor);
    Log.v(TAG, valor);
}


public ArrayList<String> getLista(){
    return array;
}

}
```

Debido a que tengo este error no he llamado al array al segundo activity por lo que no lo pondré

Comment: me parece a tu algoritmo tiene recursión infinita? insertar() llama a grr() y grr() llama a insertar() y así sucesivamente :/

Comment: Tienes razón, ya revisé el logcat y así es... Alguna idea como resolverlo?

Comment: nose que quieres hacer , porque no explicas mejor con más detalle

Comment: Tengo 3 clases: Activity1 , Array y Activity2. Desde el Activity1 añadir por medio de una variable en la misma un item al array en la clase array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu Activity1

```
     Array array = new Array();


//aqui agregas tu lista de elementos que pertenece al objeto array
     public void grr(){
        Log.v(TAG, k);

        array.insertar(k);
     }


//con este metodo puedes llamar a los elementos del objeto array
    public ArrayList<String> listarArray(){
        return array.getLista();
    }


Tu clase array


//CLASE QUE CONTIENE EL ARRAY
public class Array {
private  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
ProductoDetailFragment Item=new ProductoDetailFragment();


public void insertar(String valor){
    array.add(valor);
    Log.v(TAG, valor);
}


public ArrayList<String> getLista(){
    return array;
}

}
```

Comment: Lo hice y me muestra el siguiente error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.juan.henet.ambielectric, PID: 6258
                                                                           java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Comment: ese error es de recursividad infinita , actualiza tu código en la pregunta para ver que hiciste

Comment: Ya lo arregle quitando ProductoDetailFragment Item=new ProductoDetailFragment(); de la clase array, pero aunque la variable K tiene valor, no se agrega al array, con un log confirmo que si tiene valor pero no se añade, tendrá algo que ver el hecho que uso un fragment para insertar desde el activity?

Comment: Actualoza el codigo para revisar

Comment: Listo, puse todo el fragment del activity

Comment: ok , que te falla de ese código? yo veo que si llena, que necesitas?